# Separating Axis Theorom - false positive on vertical axis

Tags: c++, math, collision, axis, theorem

I've implemented a collision detecting using *SAT* and I get false positives if another `bbox` is above or below the bounding box.

I'm projecting each (for now) axis aligned face of the bounding box against its own and the other `bbox` corners.

The collision data returned is correct `(depth, stepheight)`, but the fact that it returns a collision for each object that is above or below the bounding box is `ofc` false.

I check my results against a simple `aabb` collision check which works.

Here is the code:

```
//------------------------------
BoundingBoxIntersectionResult BoundingBox::IntersectionSAT(BoundingBox & other)
{

    // check shortest edge
    f32 distances[6] = {
        (other.mMaxVec.x - this->mMinVec.x),
        (this->mMaxVec.x - other.mMinVec.x),
        (other.mMaxVec.y - this->mMinVec.y),
        (this->mMaxVec.y - other.mMinVec.y),
        (other.mMaxVec.z - this->mMinVec.z),
        (this->mMaxVec.z - other.mMinVec.z)
    };

    i32 faceIndex = 0;
    Vec3 faceNormal;
    f32 collisionDepth = 0.0f;

    // for each face normal, get the minimum and maximum extens of the projection 
    // of all corner points of both shapes
    // if they dont overlap, there is no intersection

    // check each normal
    for (ui32 i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        // CornerPointsWorld represents the world space corner positions
        SATReturn ret = this->SATTest(this->mNormals[i], this->mCornerPointsWorld);
        SATReturn ret2 = this->SATTest(this->mNormals[i], other.mCornerPointsWorld);

        float d1 = ret.minAlong - ret2.maxAlong;
        float d2 = ret2.minAlong - ret.maxAlong;
        if ((d1 > 0.0f) || (d2> 0.0f))
        {
            // return a false collision event, because we got a seperating axis
            return { false, 0.0f, 0.0f, Vec3(), BBOX_SIDE_LEFT };
        }
    }


    // check each normal of the other bbox
    for (ui32 i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        SATReturn ret = this->SATTest(other.mNormals[i], this->mCornerPointsWorld);
        SATReturn ret2 = this->SATTest(other.mNormals[i], other.mCornerPointsWorld);

        float d1 = ret.minAlong - ret2.maxAlong;
        float d2 = ret2.minAlong - ret.maxAlong;
        if ((d1 > 0.0f) || (d2> 0.0f))
        {
            // return a false collision event, because we got a seperating axis
            return { false, 0.0f, 0.0f, Vec3(), BBOX_SIDE_LEFT };
        }

        // get collision data
        if (i == 0 || distances[i] < collisionDepth)
        {
            faceIndex = i;
            faceNormal = this->mNormals[i];
            collisionDepth = distances[i];
        }
    }

    // get step height needed to climb this object
    f32 stepHeight = other.mMaxVec.y - this->mMinVec.y;

    return { true, collisionDepth, stepHeight, faceNormal, BoundingBoxSide(faceIndex) };
}


//------------------------------
SATReturn BoundingBox::SATTest(Vec3& normal, Vector<Vec3>& corners)
{
    SATReturn ret;
    ret.maxAlong = MIN_FLOAT;
    ret.minAlong = MAX_FLOAT;

    // for each point
    for (ui32 i = 0; i < corners.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        f32 dot = Vec3::Dot(corners[i], normal);
        if (dot < ret.minAlong) ret.minAlong = dot;
        if (dot > ret.maxAlong) ret.maxAlong = dot;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

where face normals are defined as:

```
Vec3 mNormals[6] =
    {
        Vec3(1,  0,  0), // left
        Vec3(-1,  0,  0), // right
        Vec3(0,  1,  0), // up
        Vec3(0,  -1,  0), // down
        Vec3(0,  0,  1), //back
        Vec3(0,  0,  -1), // front
    };
```

I've added a screenshot to display the problem:

[image: sat false positive]

### So the problem is:

It returns false positive for all objects below or above the bounding box.

Comment: i can simply fix this by checking that collisionDepth > 0.0. but that doesnt make the SAT correct. because the distances are axis aligned

Comment: Looking at your code I don't see anything wrong with it. What are the relations between Min/MaxVec and CornerPointsWorld? Is there a matrix transforming the former to the latter? Perhaps the bug is hiding there?

Comment: i initialize both cornerPointsLocal and cornerPointsWorld with the same data. as soon as transform is called, cornerPointsLocal is multiplied with the matrix and stored in cornerPointsWorld. if i check the min and max vector with distances (simple aabb-aabb) test, it works fine. Ive pasted the main code involving transform and local and world points here: http://codepaste.net/og75wd

Comment: could it be that the problem is that i have right = -x, up = +y, far = +z. looks like my corner points are wrong because of that. have to look into that after work tomorrow.

Comment: I have a feeling this is your problem:

  `f32 height = this->mMaxVec.x - this->mMinVec.y;`
  `f32 width = this->mMaxVec.x - this->mMinVec.x;`

There's a copy-paste mistake in the first line.

Comment: oh boy. cant wait to try it out tomorrow. thanks for the hint

Comment: tested and it works. the aabb code always worked because it used the min and max vectors, recalculated from the world space corners. and it seems that this typo didnt cause to alter that hull.